# Path.GetFullPath Function searches only in Current Project

Tags: c#, file, directory, filepath

```
    private static void saveDirAndFiles(TreeNode currNode)
    {

        using (StreamWriter file =  new StreamWriter("test.html"))
        {
            if(currNode.ValueType=="DIR") //Are you a File or Directory
            {
                file.WriteLine(currNode.Value);//relative Name of Directory
            }
            else
            {
                string[] file1 = File.ReadAllLines(Path.GetFullPath(currNode.Value)); //EXEPTION

                string prgcode = "";
                foreach (string line in file1)
                {
                    prgcode += line;
                }

                file.WriteLine(currNode.Value);//relative Name of File +...
                file.WriteLine(String.Format("<code><pre>{0}</pre></code>", prgcode)); //... The Content of the File
            }

        }
        foreach (TreeNode item in currNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            saveDirAndFiles(item);
        }

    }
```

The function searches the absolute Path only in the project I'm currently working on. My Project is on the Desktop the file Name is on the C Directory. The Exception says : Project\bin\debug\Filename not found.

Comment: `Path.GetFullPath` does not search the drive. [Read the documentation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath(v=vs.110).aspx) Even if it did search, then you have the problem of what if there are two files named "Filename", in two different directories? You need to get the name of the directory, either from the user or from a configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

`Path.GetFullPath` gives you the absolute file path for a given path sequence that may be either absolute or relative. It does not even check whether the file exists, nor does it perform a search in the file system.

If you want to load your files from somewhere else, you thus have two options: Either you rebase the relative path explicitly to a different base path using `Path.Combine` (preferable option) or you change the environments current working directory (may have side-effects in other parts of your application).

Comment: how do you use Path.Combine in this situation. How can I get to the Name of the Directory so I can combine it with the File?

Comment: You have to know the base path or ask the user, e.g., using a folder select dialog.